# Does Democratic Federation of Northern Syria have any official foreign relations?

Tags: international-relations, syria, foreign-policy

The [Democratic Federation of Northern Syria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Federation_of_Northern_Syria) is described in Wikipedia as being a "*de facto* autonomous region in northern Syria," gaining its autonomy from the Syrian government as part of the current civil war.

They apparently have their origins in the Kurdish nationalist movement making the United States a major backer, but they seem to still be quite far away from any official recognition by any country. The ongoing conflict would cause most countries to stop short of any type of official recognition until it is settled, but their organization and public statements regarding equality, property rights and other ideals sounds entirely antithetical to other governments in the region and I believe would draw strong support from most if not all Western nations.

My question is what is the status of this region in the wider international community? Do they have any embassies set up in other countries, or have they entered into any public agreements between other nations of any kind (aid / trade)?

Comment: There are frequent conferences on the future of Syria and sometimes the warring opposition fractions send representatives. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_II_Conference_on_Syria#Syrian_participation

Comment: I don't think they aim to be independent, but rather to aim to be an autonomous region of a federal Syria.  As such, they wouldn't seek official recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Wikipedia says:-

The region's most notable role in the international arena is comprehensive military cooperation of its militias under the Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF) umbrella with the United States and the international (US-led) coalition against the Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant. In a public statement in March 2016, the day after the declaration of the regions autonomy, U.S. Defense Secretary Ashton Carter praised the People's Protection Units (YPG) militia as having "proven to be excellent partners of ours on the ground in fighting ISIL. We are grateful for that, and we intend to continue to do that, recognizing the complexities of their regional role." At various times, the U.S. deployed U.S. troops embedded with the SDF to the border between the region and Turkey, in order to deter Turkish aggressions against the SDF. In February 2018, the United States Department of Defense released a budget blueprint for 2019 which with respect to the Democratic Federation of Northern Syria included $300 million for the Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF) and $250 million for border security.[224] In April 2018, the President of France, Emmanuel Macron dispatched troops to Manbij and Rmelan in a bid to assist Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF) militias and in order to defuse tensions with Turkey.

According to some more research, Russia also supports more autonomy to the regional Kurds ruling the area and federalisation of Syria once freed from ISIS. They have diplomatic missions in The US, The European Union and Russia. For further information https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_the_Democratic_Federation_of_Northern_Syria

Answer (score -1):

No. They are exactly that. An autonomous region of Syria. In an ideal world, according to the U.N charter of self determination the Kurds should have a country in what today encompasses Turkey, Syria, Iraq and Iran. But even the Kurds, despite having support from the U.S know this is not a possibility.

At most what they can negotiate is more autonomy in Syria from what they already had. Given that Turkey, who are very much opposed to any Kurdish autonomy or independent state, is a NATO member, it's very unlikely that the U.S will support that. They will just remain being a pawn in a much greater geopolitical game.

Western powers will once again reap the benefits of how they carved up the lands in the middle east not depending on the people that lived there, but how they could control them more easily. And racist people will use this as an argument claiming that Islam is the "religion of peace".

Comment: I just got a notification this was upvoted. And then 20 second later it was downvoted again. But at least this answer aged well. Glad to see, that so far, I'm still right.